# Get some string from field meta_key using query mysql (table wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have 2 field from table wordpress (meta_key and meta_value) , where value from meta_key is repeatable_fields and value from meta_value is :

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Player";s:6:"select";s:3:"mp4";s:6:"idioma";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:77:"https://1fhjm39.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/-PoiLZ6qQtweKBKM/_wm0lMJhOHM/5651-muxed.mp4";}}
```

and my question is , can i get only `https://1fhjm39.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/-PoiLZ6qQtweKBKM/_wm0lMJhOHM/5651-muxed.mp4` using mysql query ?

here my query for get all data :

```
Select ID, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title,
       post_status, post_name, post_type,
    max(case when meta_key = 'dt_poster' then meta_value end) as gambar,
    max(case when meta_key = 'imdbRating' then meta_value end) as rating,
     max(case when meta_key = 'repeatable_fields' then meta_value end) as url

from get_movies
where post_status = 'publish' and post_type = 'movies' and
      meta_key in ('dt_poster', 'imdbRating','repeatable_fields')
group by ID, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title,
         post_status, post_name, post_type order by ID desc
```

and i need passing from repeatable_fields to field url

Comment: why don't unserialize this data and get the  url? is there any issue? Also show us what query you tried so far which gives you current output? Also which met_key have that url as it's meta_value. Please add all these info to your question to get good and quicker answer.

Comment: check my edit, i need on query mysql

Comment: when you are using Wordpress then use it's query syntax.Check this:- [Wprdpress meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) And [Wordpress meta query helping thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227144/meta-query-key-value-from-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mydata_url = 'a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Player";s:6:"select";s:3:"mp4";s:6:"idioma";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:77:"https://1fhjm39.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/-PoiLZ6qQtweKBKM/_wm0lMJhOHM/5651-muxed.mp4";}}';

$mydata_url_set = unserialize($mydata_url);
echo $mydata_url_set[0]['url'];
```